# PHP - MySQL Search database table return result with percentage match

Tags: php, mysql, count, subquery, match

On my site I allow the users to select what they like or have interest in. This is done using a pre-defined drop down menu, so every time the user logs into the site they get a list of users that have the same interest as them.

This is done by taking the logged in user's interests (store in db) and matching with other user on the site, using  MySQL WHERE clause. But what I am having trouble is how to show percentage or score next to each users to show how close they match the logged in user interest.

For example:

- user1 -- 60% match to your interest
- user1 -- 30% match to your interest
- user2 -- 20% match to your interest

Each user have 5 different interest, if all match than its 100% match.

A sample of table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `helloworld` (
  `id` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `like1` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `like2` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `like3` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

example query:

```
SELECT * FROM helloworld WHERE like1='football' AND like2='art'
```

I was thinking using `COUNT` function, but I am unsure? or should I be using sub queries?

EDIT : i am using PHP for server side language. user can NOT  type their own likes, must use the pre defined list.

Comment: If I had like1='art' and like2='football', would I match the example query above?

Comment: sorry no you wont match, since art always in the like2 column not like1. Users are not allowed to type or mix and match their likes, they must choose from pre-defined list(drop down menu).   The site is implemented using php and mysql, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I do it. Assume that $like1, $like2 and $like3 are the values from your current user:

```
SELECT (IF(like1='$like1',1,0) + IF(like2='$like2',1,0) + IF(like3='$like3',1,0))/3*100 match_percent,
COUNT(id)
FROM helloworld
GROUP BY match_percent;
```

Comment: you have (incorrectly) assumed that likes will be stored in the same column - that would limit the total number of different likes in the database to just 5. wrong!

Comment: I should have asked the poster but the assumption isn't necessarily invalid. So, are all choices available for each column or does each like have a distinct set of choices? If each is distinct my code is fine, otherwise you'll need a more normalized solution.

Comment: correct all value are distinct for each column. tested your code it seems to produce  the results I am looking. but always returns one user with 0% for some reason..

Comment: I would assume that the 5 columns are a "bucket" of likes perhaps in order of priority, perhaps not, but any like column can have any like value and all like columns have different (or null) values within any given row.

Comment: @davidethell after further testing i notice you query will only return one user if a 100% match made, even though  their might be few other users that might have same interest as you and are 100% match.

Answer (score 0):

You have a many-to-mant relationship between user and likes. Your table violates 1NF - you have a "repeating group" of the `like` columns. Instead, have a separate *association* table to handle this:

```
create table user_likes (
    user_id int(9) NOT NULL,
    like_name varchar(300) NOT NULL
);
```

Now you can use simpler queries to get the count of matches - I'll leave that to you to work out :)

Hint: You could use a bit mask to help determine matches, assigning a predefined power of 2 number to each distinct like_name (help is a like_names table).

Answer (score 0):

First off, I think you need a different schema. The one you have will make your task very difficult, because it's not flexible enough.  I recommend something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id`        INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name`      VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `likes` (
    `user`      INT NOT NULL,
    `interest`  VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user`,`interest`)
);
```

(Sorry, I don't remember how to set up a FK relationship in MySQL, but I'm sure you can figure that out easily enough.)

Then, to determine the number of 'likes' for each user:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM users
JOIN likes ON likes.user=users.id
WHERE users.name = 'bob';
```

Then to determine how many likes two users have in common:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM users AS u1
JOIN likes AS l1 ON (l1.user = u1.id)
JOIN likes AS l2 ON (l1.interest = l2.interest)
JOIN users AS u2 ON (l2.user = u2.id)
WHERE u1.name = 'bob'
    AND u2.name = 'alice';
```

Then based on these three numbers, you can calculate your percentages as you wish--probably in your client code, but you could use sub-selects to do it all SQL-side if you want.

Example:

```
USERS:
 id | name
----+-------
  1 | bob
  2 | alice

LIKES:
 user | interest
------+----------
    1 | fish
    1 | baseball
    2 | fish
    2 | cooking
    2 | baseball
```

Running the first query for `bob` and `alice` will show that bob has **2** interests, and that Alice has **3** interests.  Then running the second query will show that they bob and alice together have **2** shared interests.

You can then show Bob that Alice shares 100% of his interests (2/2 = 100%), and you can show Alice that Bob shares 66% (2/3 = 66%) of her interests.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better check that at PHP level. Considering each user's interests, you may get the score using count() over the result of array_intersect() to compare the visitor and other user  interests (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php). If you allow 5 interests, that would be (5 * count(array_intersect({params})))%. For no match, 0%, for 4 matches, 80%.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it with your current schema:

```
select
    t2.id,
    t2.name
    sum(
        t1.like1 in (t2.like1, t2.like2, t2.like3, t2.like4, t2.like5) +
        t1.like2 in (t2.like1, t2.like2, t2.like3, t2.like4, t2.like5) +
        t1.like3 in (t2.like1, t2.like2, t2.like3, t2.like4, t2.like5) +
        t1.like4 in (t2.like1, t2.like2, t2.like3, t2.like4, t2.like5) +
        t1.like5 in (t2.like1, t2.like2, t2.like3, t2.like4, t2.like5)
    ) * 20 as percent_match
from helloworld t1
left join helloworld t2 on t1.id != t2.id
group by 1, 2
order by 3 desc;
```

This works because `true` in mysql is `1` - summing the truths will total the number of matches.

Comment: whats the purpose of using * 20? and anything from  t1.like2 in (t2.like1, t2.like2. t2.like3. t2.like4. t2.like5) - second line does not seem to work. do you think each of the  above should be summed separately?

Comment: syntax error still exits, i could not work it out. error was "check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sum( t1.like1 in (t2.like1, t2.like2, t2.like3, t2.like4, t2.like5) + ' at line 4"